# equalities between conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

How can I make the following equation correct by changing the order of $X,Y$ and $E$ :
$$E[X]=E[X|E[Y]]$$
and how can I prove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb E[Y]$ is a constant, hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X|E[Y]] &= \mathbb E[X|\sigma(E[Y])]\\
&=\mathbb E[X|\{\emptyset,\Omega \}]\\
&=\mathbb E[X]
\end{align*}

The last line is because any $\{\emptyset,\Omega \}$ measurable random variable is a constant so that $\mathbb E[X|\{\emptyset,\Omega \}]$ is the constant $a$ that satisfies $\mathbb E[Xb]=\mathbb E[ab]$ for all constant $b$, now whenever $b\neq 0$, then we directly get $\mathbb E[X]=a$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: Right. What is $\sigma$ there and how follows the second equality ?

Comment: $\sigma(U)$ is the sigma field generated by $U$. If that is not talking to you, I think you should give us the definition of conditional expectation you use.

Comment: I would understand it if I knew why $$\sigma(E[Y])=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$$

Comment: Well, $\mathbb E[Y]$ is a constant, now if you want all kind of event of the form $\mathbb E[Y]\in A$ for some $A$, either it is true for all $\omega\in\Omega$, or it is false for all of them. Hence $\{\omega : \mathbb E[Y](\omega)\in A \}\in \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$